# Magento modify admin order items view called by getColumnHtml method

Tags: magento, admin

In my Magento admin I want to modify the display of ordered items in an order.

I found that the table is in design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml

and the data in design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

I need to add some data in the first column : product.

I found that this following code build the HTML : (line 68 of default.phtml in Magento 1.4)

```
<?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?>
```

I searched a lot to find where the html is build but I can't find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it :

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml

Cheers.